# ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `klass' for nil:NilClass)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, has-one-through

On using a filter related to subscription I am getting the following error -

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `klass' for nil:NilClass):
    1: insert_tag renderer_for(:index)
```

This is the user model -

```
has_one :owned_account, class_name: 'Account'
has_one :owned_subscription, through: :owned_account, source: :subscription
```

This is the subscription model -

```
belongs_to :account
has_one :owner, through: :account, source: :user
```

This is the account model -

```
belongs_to :user
has_one :subscription, dependent: :destroy
```

Is anyone having any idea how to resolve it? Any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT - This is the full trace of error**

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `klass' for nil:NilClass):
    1: insert_tag renderer_for(:index)
  activerecord (4.2.11.3) lib/active_record/reflection.rb:671:in `source_reflection'
  activerecord (4.2.11.3) lib/active_record/reflection.rb:640:in `foreign_key'
  activeadmin (1.2.1) lib/active_admin/filters/active_filter.rb:119:in `block in find_predicate_association'
  activeadmin (1.2.1) lib/active_admin/filters/active_filter.rb:119:in `each'
  activeadmin (1.2.1) lib/active_admin/filters/active_filter.rb:119:in `detect'
  activeadmin (1.2.1) lib/active_admin/filters/active_filter.rb:119:in `find_predicate_association'
  activeadmin (1.2.1) lib/active_admin/filters/active_filter.rb:110:in `predicate_association'
  activeadmin (1.2.1) lib/active_admin/filters/active_filter.rb:92:in `find_class'
  activeadmin (1.2.1) lib/active_admin/filters/active_filter.rb:16:in `initialize'
  activeadmin (1.2.1) lib/active_admin/filters/active.rb:23:in `new'
  activeadmin (1.2.1) lib/active_admin/filters/active.rb:23:in `block in build_filters'
  activeadmin (1.2.1) lib/active_admin/filters/active.rb:23:in `map'
  activeadmin (1.2.1) lib/active_admin/filters/active.rb:23:in `build_filters'
  activeadmin (1.2.1) lib/active_admin/filters/active.rb:17:in `initialize'
  activeadmin (1.2.1) lib/active_admin/filters/active_sidebar.rb:13:in `new'
  activeadmin (1.2.1) lib/active_admin/filters/active_sidebar.rb:13:in `block in block'
  activeadmin (1.2.1) lib/active_admin/views/components/sidebar_section.rb:28:in `instance_exec'
  activeadmin (1.2.1) lib/active_admin/views/components/sidebar_section.rb:28:in `build_sidebar_content'
  activeadmin (1.2.1) lib/active_admin/views/components/sidebar_section.rb:16:in `build'
  arbre (1.4.0) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:30:in `block in build_tag'
  arbre (1.4.0) lib/arbre/context.rb:93:in `with_current_arbre_element'
  arbre (1.4.0) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:49:in `with_current_arbre_element'
  arbre (1.4.0) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:26:in `build_tag'
  arbre (1.4.0) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:39:in `insert_tag'
  arbre (1.4.0) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:14:in `sidebar_section'
  activeadmin (1.2.1) lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:132:in `block (2 levels) in build_sidebar'
  activeadmin (1.2.1) lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:131:in `collect'
  activeadmin (1.2.1) lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:131:in `block in build_sidebar'
  arbre (1.4.0) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:31:in `block in build_tag'
  arbre (1.4.0) lib/arbre/context.rb:93:in `with_current_arbre_element'
  arbre (1.4.0) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:49:in `with_current_arbre_element'
  arbre (1.4.0) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:26:in `build_tag'
  arbre (1.4.0) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:39:in `insert_tag'
  arbre (1.4.0) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:14:in `div'
  activeadmin (1.2.1) lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:130:in `build_sidebar'
  activeadmin (1.2.1) lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:78:in `block in build_page_content'
  arbre (1.4.0) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:31:in `block in build_tag'
  arbre (1.4.0) lib/arbre/context.rb:93:in `with_current_arbre_element'
  arbre (1.4.0) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:49:in `with_current_arbre_element'
  arbre (1.4.0) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:26:in `build_tag'
  arbre (1.4.0) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:39:in `insert_tag'
  arbre (1.4.0) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:14:in `div'
  activeadmin (1.2.1) lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:76:in `build_page_content'
  activeadmin (1.2.1) lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in build_page'
  arbre (1.4.0) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:31:in `block in build_tag'
  arbre (1.4.0) lib/arbre/context.rb:93:in `with_current_arbre_element'
  arbre (1.4.0) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:49:in `with_current_arbre_element'
  arbre (1.4.0) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:26:in `build_tag'
  arbre (1.4.0) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:39:in `insert_tag'
  arbre (1.4.0) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:14:in `div'
  activeadmin (1.2.1) lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:50:in `block in build_page'
  arbre (1.4.0) lib/arbre/context.rb:93:in `with_current_arbre_element'
  arbre (1.4.0) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:49:in `with_current_arbre_element'
  activeadmin (1.2.1) lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:49:in `build_page'
  activeadmin (1.2.1) lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:10:in `build'
  arbre (1.4.0) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:30:in `block in build_tag'
  arbre (1.4.0) lib/arbre/context.rb:93:in `with_current_arbre_element'
  arbre (1.4.0) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:26:in `build_tag'
  arbre (1.4.0) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:39:in `insert_tag'
```

Comment: We need more info about that error.

Comment: @razvans I have added the full trace of error for more clarification.

Answer (score 0):

not sure about the error, but in the `subcription` model,
shouldn't it be `belongs_to owner`;
And more about association problems with undefined method 'klass' for nil:NilClass in the link below

reference:
https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/issues/611